# OpenGL ES 2.0 with static (Fixed Function) pipeline API?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I know that OpenGL ES 2.0 standard threw out all the methods that can achieve the same results only keeping one. This is the result why static pipeline is removed from the specification and only dynamic pipeline is present. But it is strange that I use this code and it works:

```
glColor3f(0, 1, 1);//white
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex2f(lower.x, lower.y);
glVertex2f(upper.x, lower.y);
glVertex2f(upper.x, upper.y);
glVertex2f(lower.x, upper.y);
glEnd();
```

This API function I use belong to static pipeline, right as I draw without using a shader. BTW I do this is cocos2d-x 3.5 that is based on OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BTW I do this is cocos2d-x 3.5 that is based on OpenGL ES 2.0.

From the [cocos2d-x github page](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x) (my emphasis):

> - OpenGL ES 2.0 (mobile) / **OpenGL 2.1 (desktop)** based

You are very likely not using an GLES2 context at all, but a GL 2.1 one, which does support all of those legacy features like the fixed function pipeline and immediate mode.

Note that the immediate mode (`glBegin`/`glEnd`) was *never* a feature of GLES, not even in 1.x which did implement the fixed-function pipeline. It does only exist in legacy desktop GL. Your code will fail if you run it on mobile devices.